# command to identify the clearcase ucm view which is out of sync from stream?

Tags: clearcase-ucm

In clearcase UCM after rebase or any stream configuration change using one view the other view require "setcs -stream(CLI)" or "synchronize with stream(GUI)" button is enabled in view properties window. How to identify my view is out of sync from stream through commandline? What is the command to identify that my view is out of sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks VonC.

The below method is failed (stream config spec and view config spec is not in order sometimes).
cleartool catcs will return some uuid which we cannot compare with foundation baselines.
I have achieved this by comparing `cleartool dump -l <streamname>` output with `cleartool catcs` output.

Found the another method.

The ucmutil command `ucmutil lspvar -pvar SUM_CSPEC_ID <streamname>` will return the config_spec_id of the stream which can be compared with `cleartool catcs | grep -i identity` output.  The config_spec_id is mentioned in view config spec as identity UCM.Stream oid:uuid@vobuuid:uuid **config_spec_id** in the second line.

Comment: Interesting use of the ucmutil tool, which makes writing the script I mention in my answer much easier. +1

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the output return by a **`cleartool ls`** within an out of sync view reflects that out-of-sync status.

you can also try, as [documented in this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21206362), a cleartool checkout.
If it returns this error message:

```
cleartool: Error: Checkout is currently disabled for element "element_name".
Its config spec rule information is currently unavailable 
due to either an aborted update or an update in progress.
```

... that means the view is out of sync.

Don't forget, in some cases, to do first a:

```
 cleartool chstream -generate yourStream@\pvob
```

That is useful if a component has switched from non-writable to writable.

But if just foundation baselines have changed, then `cleartool setcs -stream` is enough.

> if all my components are read only in that stream and view(where I do only build). In that case how to check my view is out of sync?

One way would be to get:

- all foundation baselines of the stream ([with `fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm))

  ```
  cd /path/to/my/view
  myStream = $(cleartool lsstream -cview)
  myFoundationBaselines = $(cleartool descr -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp" $myStream)
  ```
- compare those baselines with the ones of the view
  (grep each baselines found in the previous step in your config spec)

  ```
   cd /path/to/your/view
   cleartool catcs
  ```

In short, there is no direct native way: you need to script it.

You will see the name of the baselines currently used by the view by grepping in a catcs for `-mkbranch`.
Those are the baseline you need to compare with the foundation baselines.

Comment: thanks for the answer. if all my components are read only in that stream and view(where I do only build). In that case how to check my view is out of sync?

Comment: @sdram I believe that you need to write a script in that case. I have edited my answer.